# How do I get the number of Spaces in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, spaces

I want the number of Spaces in OSX snow leopard.

If I use 4 spaces, I want that number 4!

I can't find a function or a class related with that.

Comment: Not sure why you would vote this one as off-topic. It is a pretty clear-cut [objective-c] tagged question asking for a class/method to get a particular value.

Comment: Yeah, I slightly agree with you. However, somehow it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information about Spaces is stored in Dock preferences. You can access the preferences via `NSUserDefaults` to get the number of rows and columns, and the number of spaces is the product of those:

```
NSDictionary *dockPrefs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.dock"];

int rows = [[dockPrefs objectForKey:@"workspaces-rows"] intValue];
int cols = [[dockPrefs objectForKey:@"workspaces-cols"] intValue];
int nspaces = rows * cols;
```